# How do I keep note of poker hand so I can benefit of it at the same hand?

Tags: online, hand-history, range

I love writing hand history so I can use it on the same hand so if I get into a sticky situation in the same hand, I can go review it and analyze his hand range--so I know if he's value betting or bluffing.

However, I find it hard to take notes of hand because people love using 'insta fold' button (especially pre-flop) or 'insta call' or 'insta check', then things goes so quickly and I lose track of it.

Dealer chat is not a good option. I sometimes over-scroll and player chats make it hard to focus.

I need four variables: their action (call/fold), how many amount money in the pot, the board and their stack.

I used notepad instead of handwriting and it is still not effective.

Comment: There is an Indian poker site adda52.com. There comes an option to view the video of all hands played and you can view the video in bottom  right corner. Contact your site admins and suggest it to them

Answer (score 1):

The way this question is worded I feel inclined to answer thusly; You are perhaps going about reviewing hands, for the most part it seems, incorrectly. I will explain this, durring I believe I will be able to answer your question.

There are two reasons I think there are flaws in this, let's say 'review game.'
First,

> I can use it on the same hand so if I get into a sticky situation in
>   the same hand, I can go review it and analyze his hand range--so I
>   know if he's value betting or bluffing.

Not exactly. Intuitively I don't suspect most people most of the time would agree that different players play the same holding in the same fashion. There are default lines, yes however, the creation and manipulation of those lines such as, you think their read on you is off, you have a good read on their play, you want to toss around their mental game etc. is a massive contributor to one's skill at poker.

Secondly, much more complex than this:

> I need four variables: their action (call/fold), how many amount money
>   in the pot, the board and their stack.

The first concept more so than 'variable' you want to remember in a hand is your position at the table. Second, who the preflop raiser was. Third your position to the one who initially raised. This gets deeper as people 3-bet and 4-bet. (Example - 6-handed: Plr1 opens 3.5bb, Plr2 calls 3.5bb ,Plr3 3-bets 11bb, Plr4 4-bets, 48bb, us to act, we fold, action folds to Plr1. Plr1 Calls, Plr2 folds, Plr3 calls. Were you in or out of position against the initial raiser? Against 4-better? Which player still in the pot is in position?)

After this is a matter of board texture and opponent reads. This is where we start finding default lines in play. If the flop comes dry, we are in position, heads up, they check.... we c-bet, clearly. So now our opponent recognizes this, and that it happens nearly 100% of the time. So he gets in a pot with us looking to check raise us. He does and we probably have to fold unless we got a piece of the flop. (Manipulation of lines now, very important)

So, label your opponents. Is this hand against someone who is a walking textbook of poker? Was this online and the player was calling every single hand b/c they don't even fully know the rules to PLO8? What have we seen this particular individual showdown in the past? Does it seem they have a fair grasp on preflop play? On flop play? Have they ever thought once about turn cards? Do they know anything about equity swings on this street? These sort of questions. (Don't over due it, in poker we need only think one step ahead.)

So in summary, reviewing hands is much more complex than variables that yield us a mathematically correct GTO answer. As we watch back our hands (Most online website record your hand history for you, I record my screen as well w/ built in Mac utilities.) we can apply what we know about poker fundamentals and default lines. We then apply some logic as to why the default is best or inoptimal according to our position (always first, most important), the board texture, our opponent history and read.